# ,cdb работа с файлами

Tags: c#

Может кто нибудь привести примеры работы с .cdb файлами? В гугле нашёл только то, что этим форматом не пользуются и вот делайте на чём нибудь другом. Необходимо создавать, добавлять записи из 6 атрибутов и удалять записи из файла. Ссылки на статейки приветствуются. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: у вас есть такой файл. Вы пробывали читаьт его ткак текстовый файл

Comment: [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.ConstantDatabase/) же. Пример использования: [demo](https://github.com/emanueldejanu/CDB.NET/blob/master/src/Cdb.DemoConsole/Main.cs).